# Exporting image from Excel with right size

Tags: image, vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet that contains some images. This a sample :

[image]

I found this VBA code to export the images to the hard drive ([link](https://superuser.com/questions/624445/how-to-save-duplicate-images-in-excel-to-different-jpegs)).

```
Sub test()
'## Open file dialog to choose a destination folder
Set FOLDER = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
FOLDER.AllowMultiSelect = False
FOLDER.Show

'## loop through all sheets and all pictures
Dim oldWidth As Integer
Dim oldHeight As Integer
For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
For Each PIC In WS.Shapes

    Set CH = WS.ChartObjects.Add(1, 1, PIC.Height, PIC.Width)

    '## save & temporarly disable the picture border
    PIC.Select
    PICBORDER = Selection.Border.LineStyle
    Selection.Border.LineStyle = 0
    PIC.Copy

    CH.Chart.ChartArea.Select

    CH.Chart.Paste

    '## re-enable the old picture border
    PIC.Select
    Selection.Border.LineStyle = PICBORDER

    '## export the chart as JPG. Change JPG to PNG if desired
    CH.Chart.Export Filename:=FOLDER.SelectedItems(1) & "\" & PIC.Name & ".jpg", FilterName:="JPG"

    '## delete chart to clean up our work
    CH.Cut

Next PIC
Next WS
End Sub
```

This code works pretty well except that the images exported are too small and contain empty space (image displayed with Windows built-in viewer).

[image]

What did I miss?

Comment: Are your `select` mandatory here? In  `PIC.Select
    PICBORDER = Selection.Border.LineStyle`, it can become `PICBORDER = PIC.Border.LineStyle` and it'll be much more efficient.
Sorry but for the size, I don't what to tell you except to add `Interactive:=True` to display a pop up to adjust image options...

Comment: It is `ChartObjects.Add(Left, Top, Width, Height)`. So try `Set CH = WS.ChartObjects.Add(1, 1, pic.Width, pic.Height)`.